# Is sunmi v2 handheld POS support printing from chrome browser?

Tags: printing, point-of-sale, sunmi

I want to print a receipt through the chrome browser. I made a money receipt using raw html,css and javascript. I send print request through javascript print() function. But I cannot able to print directly through browser. How can I print web page through browser in Sunmi v2 POS device?

Comment: You probably need a plugin provided by the vendor. [How to print receipt from web chrome browser of Sunmi V1s V2?](https://youtu.be/EbtiZBYuH7Q)

Comment: There was a `SunmiPrinterPlugin` in Sunmi App Store (orange app store icon), but nowadays when I was looking for it - this app is nowhere to be found. 
I have new Sunmi device (Sunmi V2s plus) and want to print from web browser. This plugin was working just fine for that. 
If someone has this app could you share an ".apk" file? Or if there is any other method to print from browser on that device